# Open an contextual menu using voice commands in google glass

Tags: android, google-glass, voice-recognition, google-voice

I am working on an app in that the app will open when i just give an voice command like

**"Ok,glass"->DemoApp**. and this is working fine.

Now i want is when an app is open i want to display a screen in which the **menus** are displayed in a list like following:-

**-Take a picture**

**-Write data**

**-Save Data**

and when i just give voice command like "**Take a picture**" the picture screen will open up(like start an camera).

So can any one tell me how to open an partcular activity of menus using an **voice keyword**.

Any help is appretiated. Thanks.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the documentation on the new contextual voice commands feature:

https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/voice#contextual_voice_commands